# How to add captions to textbox in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, html

I was told that in html you should put captions on input fields.
How can I do this in ASP.Net?

Comment: what do you mean by "captions"?

Comment: Can you post an image that has a field with a caption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="textcontrolid" Text="caption" />
```

**Example**

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="tbNum1" Text="Num1:" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbNum1" />
```

Comment: It's the only thing I could think of that kinda fitted the description

Comment: Can I write 
Num1: <asp:Textbox id="tbNum1" runat="server"/>?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he is just talking about the Tooltip property: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tooltip.aspx).

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFName" ToolTip="First name" />
```